# How to change the glyphicon on click event?

Tags: angular5

I am trying to change glyphicon on click event. From console I found out that classes are not set properly.

### From Inspect Element

```
<span _ngcontent-c2="" class="glyphicon-menu-up" ng-reflect-klass="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up ar" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>
```

This is the code I did in HTML part.

### CODE:

```
<ul class="nav third-nav">
    <li appExpandMenu (click)="isCollapsedA=!isCollapsedA">
        <a>
            <span [ngClass] = "{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up arrow': !isCollapsedA, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right arrow': isCollapsedA}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-{{sign}} arrow"></span>
            <span class="third-menu-title">Docs</span>
        </a>
    </li>

<ul class="nav third-nav">
        <li appExpandMenu (click)="isCollapsedA=!isCollapsedA">
            <a>
                <span [ngClass] = "{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up arrow': !isCollapsedA, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right arrow': isCollapsedA}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-{{sign}} arrow"></span>
                <span class="third-menu-title">Docs</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should apply [ngClass] like this:

```
[ngClass] ="isCollapsedA ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right arrow' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up arrow'"
```

This is perhaps the code you need .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-u5bzma?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: when I used this, my glyphicon is not changing on click

Comment: And if i have multiple then when I click on on all are changing

Comment: I have updated the answer .Have a look at the link .This is what u need perhaps

Comment: but still first one is controlling second one initially

Comment: I got it but when i click first and then second then first one closes and then next click opens it. I dont want to click 2 times. If first is clicked and then second is clicked first to be closed and second to open in single click

Comment: got your concern ..stackblitz has been updated ... have a look